# Azure expressjs web apps

Tags: node.js, express, azure-web-app-service

I have created an express application in Visual Studio. I am having problems running it in azure once I've hosted. 
It does not seem to find my node_modules folder.

Whenever I deploy and visit the site, on Kudu under the /logStream url I receive the error

> cannot find module 'debug'

I found out that the debug module was required in the www folder. I then removed it from there and redeployed.

After redeployment I get

> cannot find module 'express'

When I run my app in production (locally), I do not experience these problems.

One suggestion was removing the node_modules folder and then publish to Azure, with that you then use npm install on Kudu powershell or cmd. I have tried this and the same errors still come back. Could you please direct me on how I can resolve this?

package.json:

```
   {
   "name":"app-name",
   "version":"0.0.0",
   "private":true,
   "scripts":{
      "start":"node ./bin/www"
   },
   "description":"descrt",
   "author":{
      "name":"myname",
      "email":"myemail@smtpserver.com"
   },
   "dependencies":{
      "body-parser":"~1.8.1",
      "cookie-parser":"~1.3.3",
      "debug":"~2.0.0",
      "express":"~4.9.0",
      "jade":"~1.6.0",
      "morgan":"~1.3.0",
      "request":"^2.72.0",
      "serve-favicon":"~2.1.3",
      "stylus":"0.42.3"
   }
}
```

Comment: paste the contents of your `package.json`, please.

Comment: This is my package.json file

Comment: {
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "description": "descrt",
  "author": {
    "name": "myname",
    "email": "myemail@smtpserver.com"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "debug": "~2.0.0",
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "jade": "~1.6.0",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3",
    "stylus": "0.42.3"
  }
}

Comment: your `package.json` is unreadable in a comment. please [edit] your question to include it and be sure to use proper code formatting. thanks.